# Using a String vector in assembly

Tags: string, assembly, x86, x86-16

I need to do a array of strings in intel 8086 assembly like this, for example:

```
.DATA

myvec dw 5 dup('string1','string2','string3','string4','string5')

(...)

.CODE

lea si, myvec[1]

call PRINT_STRING

(...)
```

But this code doesn't work with strings, only letter-by-letter. How this can be done? I need when accessing the 1 position vector, for example, it accesses a full string, not just a letter.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to specify each string separately, then create a list of the addresses to each of those strings.

```
.DATA

str1 db "string1",0
str2 db "string2",0
str3 db "string3",0
str4 db "string4",0
str5 db "string5",0

myvec dw str1,str2,str3,str4,str5
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken (quite possible), he wants `offset str1`, etc.

Comment: I don't remember the specifics of MASM syntax, but if that gives the address of `str1`, then yes, you're right.